# RecyclerView with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter showing wrong values when scrolling

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

In my Activity, I use a `RecyclerView` that uses a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to draw a list:

```
mChatDetailsAdapter = new ChatDetailsAdapter(
            this,
            MessageData.class,
            R.layout.layout_chat_item,
            ChatDetailsAdapter.MessageViewHolder.class,
            query);
    mChatListView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager lLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ChatDetailsActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    lLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    lLinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mChatListView.setLayoutManager(lLinearLayoutManager);
    mChatListView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(UIUtils.dpToPx(ChatDetailsActivity.this, 8)));
    mChatListView.setAdapter(mChatDetailsAdapter);
```

The Adapter takes care about the views:

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder pViewHolder, final MessageData pMessageData, int pPosition) {
        pViewHolder.mMessageTextView.setText(pMessageData.getMessage());
        pViewHolder.mSelfLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pViewHolder.mTimeTExtView.setText(StringUtils.toMessageTimeString(mContext, pMessageData.getTime()));
}
```

In the `onBindViewHolder()` method I basically do the same, be assigning the data from the model (works correctly after looking at the log messages). Now when scrolling the list the `RecyclerView` changes its values and doesn't recycle correctly and I have no idea why. Any idea?

Comment: please show us how you stored the data in the  firebase database